# How to calculate results by using two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculation

[image]

I have two data frames Df1 and Df2. I want to choose the value where name is B from Df1 and multiply that number with the column weight in Df2 so that I get a new result column like in the new data frame Df2 new.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's recommended to add your data as plain text, we can not copy the contents from image. Please take a look at [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: the picture is only for illustration purposes, other numbers can also be used, I am only concerned with the principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `'B'` is unique within the `name` column of `df1`, you can look up the value in `df1` and multiply it by the `weight` column of `df2` like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                    'value': [100, 300, 150]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'no': [115, 99, 76],
                    'weight': [.3, .5, .2]})

df2['result'] = df1.value.values[df1.name == 'B'] * df2.weight
print(df2)
```

```
    no  weight  result
0  115     0.3    90.0
1   99     0.5   150.0
2   76     0.2    60.0
```

The weight values should of course be given as float numbers within the dataframe, not strings containing percentage signs.